# Movie about soldiers fighting robots in a parallel timeline, and a scientist traveling between timelines

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, timeline

The main character in the movie was a man with black curly hair and glasses, who was a scientist, and he had a wife. This man was involved in an experiment traveling to other parallel timelines. He stepped through a stargate like device, and was immediately teleported to another timeline.

Somehow, activating this device enabled robots from another timeline to invade. These robots were made out of very angular armor, like a cross between a medieval European knight and the Tesla Cybertruck. These robots had a gun on one arm that shot fireballs which exploded. It was very hard to kill them as they were super durable. They also walked very slowly, making a lot of noise when they stepped.

The first timeline or parallel universe that this scientist went to was located in the middle of the desert. He landed next to a family who were camping in the desert, a father, a mother, and a son. Suddenly the first of the invading robots came out of the portal. It shot a fireball at the family, and apparently severely injured the boy. The father thought that the scientist was controlling the robot and yelled at him, "damn government experiments, you can't go out camping in the desert no more". When they were driving away in their car the robot shot another fire ball at them but it missed.

Then the next timeline that the scientist traveled to. He came into a parallel timeline, assuming the body of his alternate self. He was apparently dressed in a soldier's uniform, and there were other soldiers next to him, who were his comrades. He didn't recognize the soldiers, but these men acted like they had known him all his life. But he didn't recognize them because although his body was in this parallel timeline, his soul came from an alternate timeline.

The soldiers eventually led him back to the base. He examined his body, and found several tattoos that his former self from this timeline had gotten. Then eventually he found his wife on the military base, but she was another soldier and she didn't recognize him. She was isolated from the rest of the soldiers because there had been some kind of pandemic, and she was infected with the virus. This scientist still thought of the woman as his wife however, despite his former self from this parallel timeline not having any prior relationships with this woman. This scientist man started dating this woman who was to be his wife, and then he kissed her. She was amazed at his act, that he was not afraid of getting the virus from her. After that she opened up to him and began to love and trust him. She believed his story that she was his wife from another timeline, and she decided to become his wife in this one also.

Acting on his former memories, this man decided that the only way to end the robot invasion was to close the portal, which was located in the science lab. He decided to lead an expedition with the soldiers to the parallel timeline version of the science lab. The captain was surprised, "I had previously thought of you as just a tech soldier, but it turns out that you are a tough guy. All right, tough guy, let's see what you're made of." The captain agreed to the expedition.

They went to the science lab on foot, and they got there by the end of the day, but not without destroying several robots along the way. The door to the lab was locked, but the scientist remembered the password to the keypad, and the door opened. The captain grabbed the scientist and interrogated him, "Tell me, how did you know that password to the keypad?" Then a robot went through the portal in the science lab, and it shot the captain and blew his head off. The scientist shot the robot and it exploded. Then he went through the portal for the last time, shutting it down in the process, so that no more robots could come through it.

When he came out of the portal, he was back in the original timeline, and he was reunited with his wife, who was pregnant.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is probably ***[A.P.E.X.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109144/?ref_=tt_urv)*** (1994).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.P.E.X.):

> *A.P.E.X* is a 1994 science fiction action film directed by Phillip J. Roth and starring Richard Keats, Mitchell Cox, Lisa Ann Russell, and Marcus Aurelius. The plot concerns a group of scientists who explore the past using robotic probes known as the A.P.E.X or "Advanced Prototype Exploration units".

> In 2073, Nicholas Sinclair is a scientist on a time travel project. An accident introduces in 1973 a deadly virus that activates the project's automatic countermeasures. Attack robots are sent to the past in an effort to eliminate the virus carriers. They fail. Sinclair returns to 2073 to find the Earth in ruins, ravaged by both the virus and the robots still in countermeasure action. Sinclair returns to the project lab that is now in ruins in order to prevent the original cause of the accident.

The general plot seems to fit your description, as does the main character, and the film does end with him returning home to his pregnant wife, as shown around the [1:39:43](https://youtu.be/4Adt_vSJa8c?t=5983) mark in the video below.

Comment: That's it. That's the movie. Good find.